# Codeigniter Make html table created from php clickable

Tags: jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I made a html table from inside the controller and echo it in the modal and the next thing I need to add is to add an edit button in every row of the table. I accomplished it all well but when I try to add a click event in the edit button, it will not work. Do I need to put jquery inside controller to make it work? Does someone encountered this problem already? Please do share your solution....
 This is the table that I made inside controller:

```
echo "<tr>
                <td><button type='button' class='btn btn-default' id='btnEditTime' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalEditTime' data-id='".$val['id']."'>Edit</a></td>
                 <td>".$val['dt']."</td>
               <td>$TimeIn</td>
                <td>$LunchOut</td>
                 <td>$RNDLIN</td>
                  <td>$RNDOUT</td>
                   <td>$Overtime</td>
                    </tr>";
```

and this is the jquery event that I am testing:

```
$('#btnEditTime').click(function(){
console.log('You clicked');
});
```

Please do take note that I tried to put a sample table with the same page of the jquery, the button works but if put it inside the controller it does not work... Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
$(document).on('click','#btnEditTime', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('You clicked');
});
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Yes it works thanks but why does my modal stop scrolling after I clicked the button?

Comment: What do you mean 'modal stop scrolling' ?

Comment: At first when the modal is loaded, it is the one scrolling but after button click, the modal stops scrolling and the scroll event is now in the background...

Comment: There might be something with your css or your other javascript code that handles that modal.

Comment: I put all my modals in one folder. Maybe the focus was transferred to the background body...